# J1 and J2 visa renewal

Tags: usa, working-visas

I am a J1 visa holder and my partner is a J2 dependent. I extended my job contract and we were issued new DS-2019s, but our visa (entry documents) are expired. Is my partner able to travel home (to Australia/New Zealand) and renew his entry documents without me, or do I need to be present for the interview when he applies? Any advice would be most appreciated!

Clarifying: we both have valid, continuing DS-2019s, but expired entry documents.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to be present. Your I-94 and DS-2019 showing that you are in J1 status should be enough.